# Consistent Reliable Messaging

Tags: logging, redundancy, apache-flume, scribe

Im working a new project,

Im currently deciding between

flume & scribe for messaging systems... ( most probably sent to logs or hadoop )

I cannot lose a message ever..
 What are your thoughts on which is better? Configuration/reliablity/adminitration wise.

If you have used / administrated both is also quite relative to answering my question.. :D

Cheers

Comment: relative or relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By far Flume is a better alternative..**

*Flume is a distributed, reliable, and available service for efficiently collecting, aggregating, and moving large amounts of log data..*

Flume provides

- Continuous, high-performance, scalability
- Reliable data loading and data flow monitoring from feeds
- Logging directly to HDFS securely (made for hadoop)
- Flexible reliability across the messaging system ( never lose a message )
- Multiple source/collection types ( running on a port / logging from Apache / Syslog securely )
- Robust and fault tolerant with tunable reliability mechanisms
- Failover and recovery mechanisms

Scribe provides "somewhat" reliability, but not as comprehensive or flexible.
secondly its compilation and usability is difficult in comparison to flume..

Hope this Helps :D